# Limit CPU usage of a Python Bottle webserver

Tags: python, cpu, cpu-usage, bottle, setrlimit

I'm using Python + [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) as a webserver.

As I use the production server for many other websites, I don't want Python + Bottle to eat 70% of the CPU for example.

**How is it possible to limit the CPU usage of a Python Bottle webserver?**

I was thinking about using [resource.setrlimit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html),  but is this a good way to do it?

With which syntax should we use `resource.setrlimit` to set the limit to 20% of the CPU for example?

Comment: It's better to set the priority of the process (and not use the `setrlimit` function).

Comment: Consider running it in a Docker.

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1

You should ask yourself whether resource optimization is really necessary. If you're certain that specific application consumes too much resources than it could or should then go to step 2.

### Step 2

When your application consumes too much resources, first thing you should do is try to identify bottlenecks in it and see if they can be optimized away. Python has various tools that can help you (code profilers, PyPy etc.) If there's nothing you can do in that regard, go to step 3.

### Step 3

If you absolutely must limit process resources, keep in mind that:

- OS has a very sophisticated scheduling mechanisms that do their best to ensure each running process gets a fair share of CPU time. Even on processor overload, things will still run fine (up to some point).
- if you deliberately limit CPU time of one of your processes it may respond slowly or not at all due to network timeouts.

My answer to this question is - reduce static priority of your server if you think it may starve other services but then your server may suffer from starvation when processors are overload. Using `nice` utility would be my choice as it won't litter your code.